# how to import data from excel using selenium webdriver in python

Tags: python, excel, selenium

how to import data from excel using selenium webdriver in python.

The requrement is that i have pass the fetch the dats from excel and sent to the fileds in the webpage using selenium webdrive in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import xlrd

xl_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('myExcelSheet.xls') #import sheet

xl_sheet = xl_workbook.sheet_by_index(1) #page

col= xl_sheet.col(9) #column you want data from in sheet
```

You can pull data from the col array and use it to populate fields with Selenium

Comment: Hi thanks for the input when i try to pass the value getting the error "line 348, in send_keys
    {'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)),
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, Cell found"